# HTML/CSS: Remove vertical scroll with height: 100%;

Tags: html, css, height

I'm creating two columns that I want to fill the page.  Very simple.  However, I'm getting a very slight vertical scrollbar. Setting `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` on the `html` and `body` didn't fix it.

I've looked into `overflow: hidden` but I don't like it.  I also looked into placing a `clear:both` div at the bottom, but that didn't do anything.  I've looked into using `min-height`, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I have two questions:

1. Why is that vertical scrollbar appearing?
2. How can I remove the vertical scrollbar?

**Live Example:**  http://jsfiddle.net/XrYYA/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="palette">Palette</div>
    <div id="canvas">Content</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#palette {
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#canvas {
margin-left: 300px;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the 1px borders on each side of the element.

100% + 2px border(s) != 100%.

You could use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include the borders in the height of the element.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NkAEk/)

```
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to subtract the 2px.

```
height: calc(100% - 2px);
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJHTh/)